# 'Services_Twilio' not found - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-php

As far as I understand, I cannot simply use `use Twilio` to make it work. Thus, I tried `require_once` and `require`. The path should also be correct

I tried using require_once

```
    $twilioDir = '../vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php';
    require_once($twilioDir);

    $client = new Services_Twilio($_ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], $_ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']);
```

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Services_Twilio' not found

What am I doing wrong?

---

Also, using `require` gave me error:

> Cannot redeclare Services_Twilio_autoload() (previously declared in /var/www/Laravel/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php:9)

I tried adding false to the line `spl_autoload_register('Services_Twilio_autoload', false);` in Twilio.php, but no luck

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand, I cannot simply use `use Twilio` to make it work.

Correct, because the class is named `Services_Twilio`.

`use Services_Twilio;` should do the trick.

Laravel handles autoloading for you. You shouldn't need to manually `require` the library unless Twilio has goofed something in their Composer setup.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know who told you that you can't `use Twilio` but you can certainly `use Twilio`.

1. Grab the composer package  - `composer require aloha/twilio`
2. Register the `ServiceProvider` in `app.php` like any other vendor: `'Aloha\Twilio\Support\Laravel\ServiceProvider',` should be added to the `providers` array.
3. Register the facade to make life easy - in `app.php` add to the `aliases` array: `'Twilio' => 'Aloha\Twilio\Support\Laravel\Facade',`
4. (optional) run `php artisan vendor:publish` so you can manage the assets that the vendor exposes to you.
5. Because we previously added the `facade` to the `aliases` array in our `app.php` we can correctly `use Twilio;` within our classes.
6. If you didn't do 3, then you need to reference the full namespace path; `use Aloha\Twilio\Support\Laravel\Facade` which will give you access to `Twilio::` inside of that particular file.

**Edit**

I should note that you do not `use Twilio` from within the class, you must reference it outside of the class **and** before the class.

```
use Twilio; //Aloha\Twilio\Support\Laravel\Facade

class MyController {
    /**
     * Now you can use Twilio::whatever
     */
}
```

Comment: I used `composer require twilio/sdk`. Did I download the wrong thing from composer?

Comment: @senty I believe that you are my friend. What you downloaded was actually just the standalone SDK or Twilio. What `aloha twilio` does is provide you the same functionality but with Laravel (4/5) integration.

Comment: I installed the right one. Now I started getting error: `Call to undefined method Aloha\Twilio\Support\Laravel\Facade::message()`  :/

Comment: @senty Doesn't sound like you registered the `ServiceProvider` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it at the top of the file.

I am not sure about the full path to the file but I am guessing it should be something like:

`use Twilio\SDK\Services\Twilio`

Update:
Follow the guide here:
https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio

Comment: But it's should be called `Services_Twilio`, no?

Comment: Yeah, whatever the path is.

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36074014/470749) didn't work for me.

Background: My code had worked for a while with `use Services_Twilio;`, but then I stopped using Twilio for months (or maybe more than a year), and then I was getting this error.

What ended up working was updating my code to say `use Twilio\Rest\Client;` instead and then create the client object via `new Client($this->config['account_sid'], $this->config['auth_token']);`.

This seems to be Twilio's newer way of doing things.

[These docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/php) helped.